# How do I search a database row by row with unknown index?

Tags: c#, sql

How do I search a database row by row with unknown index?  I have a situation working with a database with an index column but if a row is deleted, the index value is never reassigned.  So how would I traverse the database, row by row if I have no idea of the index values?

Comment: Select * from table1 orderby xxxxx.  An SQL Database is store to speed read/write times and may not be in any particular order so it is always best to use an orderby.

Comment: Your question really needs sample data and a better description of what you are trying to do.